# using RPI 3.3v and 5v pins as reference for level shifter

Tags: rpi.gpio

As the title says, simply, can I use the 3.3v and 5v power pins on the GPIO connector as the reference voltages for a level shifter, or do I need some other reference?

Comment: Why does a level shifter need a reference voltage?  You probably need to reference the device you are planning to use.

Answer (score 1):

"Reference voltage"... do you mean supply voltage?

#### The answer to your question is: "Yes - you can probably use RPi's 3.3V & 5V supples to power your level shifter.".

The caveat was added because you didn't specify a *particular* device, and there are [*many* devices called "level shifters"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=level+shifter+ic&t=ffnt&ia=web).

Both the 3.3V and 5V regulators on the RPi have some "excess" capacity - by that I mean they are able to source more current than is typically used by the RPi, while maintaining specified voltage levels. See [REF1](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin2_5v_power#) and [REF2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51616/83790) for details. Typical "level shifters" such as [this one from AdaFruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/395), and [this one from Texas Instruments](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lv1t34.pdf?ts=1592174224225&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DSN74LV1T34DCKRG4%2526keyMatch%253DLEVEL%2BSHIFTER%2526tisearch%253DSearch-EN-everything) can be powered from the RPi regulated supplies.

If you want to minimize clutter and wiring, you may prefer a level shifter that operates from a single supply (e.g. 5V). The Texas Instruments part linked above is one example of a single-supply level shifter.

Comment: Thanks....that's the exact answer that I was looking for. I'd like to make a 'HAT" for my RPI parts with bi-directional level shifters just to protect the GPIO for accidental connection to 5VDC I/O, and will use the same parts as the AdaFruit modules, but not those modules, because they cost too much to put on the 10 RPI that I have.

I'm probably being rediculously paranoid, but that's where I'd like to go.

Comment: @crusader27529: Glad it helped. [Please read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The High and Low voltage pins of a level shifter should be connected to the respective supply voltages of the 2 devices it is intended to interface.